# Disabled not working inside NgFor with form

Tags: angular

After adding a new user, the previous user inputs loses the disabled, the same happens with `*ngFor="let user in users.slice().reverse()"` insted of unshift.

```
addUser() {
  this.users.unshift({
    id: 2,
    email: 'test1@test.ad',
    checkbox: false,
    disabled: false,
  });
}
```

HTML:

```
<button mat-mini-fab (click)="addUser()">add</button>
<form #elementForm="ngForm" name="elementForm" class="w-full">
  <div *ngFor="let user of users; let i = index">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="always">
       <mat-label>Email {{ user.disabled }}</mat-label>
          <input matInput type="email" name="email{{ i }}" [(ngModel)]="user.email [disabled]="user.disabled" />
       </mat-form-field>

       <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="user.checkbox" [name]="'checkbox' + i [disabled]="user.disabled">Checkbox {{ user.disabled }}</mat-checkbox>
   </div>
</form>
```

Everything works fine without form

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dqsyk9?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

name attribute should be unique for input element. Create name attribute with unique id instead of index.

```
  <form #elementForm="ngForm" name="elementForm" class="w-full">
  <div *ngFor="let user of users; let i = index">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="always">
      <mat-label>Email {{ user.disabled }}</mat-label>
      <input
        matInput
        [disabled]="user.disabled"
        type="email"
        name="email{{ user.id }}"
        [(ngModel)]="user.email"
      />
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-checkbox
      [disabled]="user.disabled"
      [(ngModel)]="user.checkbox"
      [name]="'checkbox' + user.id"
      >Email {{ user.disabled }}</mat-checkbox
    >
  </div>
</form>
```

**[Working Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zikegp?file=src/app/app.component.html)**